# Cannot Convert CGFLoat to CGPoint

Tags: swift

I am trying to add two variables together that are `CGFloat`, but I am getting this compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'
```

Here is the code that is giving me the error:

```swift
let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: moveTo func is requiring a CGPoint, you are trying to pass CGFloat by adding height.

Comment: what do you mean? chirag90

Comment: `SKAction.moveTo` expects to have `CGPoint` variables passed into it.

Your `self.size.height + bullet.size.height` calculation returns a float value. You need to convert that `CGFloat` value into a `CGPoint`. You can create a `CGPoint` with `CGPointMake(x,y)`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move

Comment: You should also look at the [moveTo documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-moveto?language=objc)

Comment: can someone re-write the code with the fixes.

Comment: `let position = CGPoint(x: desiredX, y: desiredY);` `let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(position, duration: 1)`

I don't know what your X and Y values should be, your question didn't specify that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the method you are using does not exist.

I guess you are looking for the method to create an action that moves the `SKSpriteNode` **vertically**.

In this case there is no need to create a `CGPoint`.

Just use this method

```
let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
```

Comment: `First of all the method you are using does not exist.` - Which method?

Comment: @nopassport1 The one mentioned in the question `SKAction.moveTo(self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)`